# How to add different components to the page on-the-fly with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My goal is to allow the user to dynamically build a form from different components, based on what they choose in a select element.  For example, they can choose to add a Heading, then maybe a Paragraph, then another Heading, etc.  Each "part" is a separate Component.

I know this sort of thing has been asked before, but I'm only day 2 into Vue and I think I'm 90% of the way there - I'm just missing something.  What I believe I'm stuck on is how to add a component to my app's data to allow Vue to render it out.

Here is the relevant markup:

```html
<div id="creator">
    <template v-for="part in existingParts">
        <component :is="part"></component>
    </template>
    <select class = "custom-select" id = "new-part-chooser" v-model="newPart" v-on:change="addPart">
        <option disabled value = "">Add a new part</option>
        <option
            v-for="part in possibleParts"
            v-bind:value="part.toLowerCase()"
            >{{ part }}</option>
    </select>
    <?php
        // These simply bring in the templates for the components
        // I know this isn't standard practice but... one thing at a time
        include 'component-heading.html';
        include 'component-paragraph.html';
    ?>
</div>
```

and my javascript file:

```js
Vue.component("part-heading",{
    data:function(){
        return {
            text: ""
        }
    },
    template:"#component-heading-template"
});
Vue.component("part-paragraph",{
    data:function(){
        return {
            text: ""
        }
    },
    template:"#component-paragraph-template"
});

const Creator = new Vue({
    el:"#creator",
    data:{
        newPart:"",
        possibleParts:[
            "Heading",
            "Paragraph"
        ],
        existingParts:[]
    },
    methods:{
        addPart:function(e){
            /*** This is where I'm stuck - what do I push here? ***/
            this.existingParts.push();
        }
    }
});
```

I've read through the docs and Google'd the hell out of the topic, but every setup seems to be just different enough that I can't figure out how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the fact that in the markup, the `:is` directive causes Vue to create a component that matches the name of the element in `existingParts`.  So `push()`-ing "part-heading" into `existingParts` causes Vue to render an instance of the "part-heading" component.

The updated, working code is:

```js
this.existingParts.push('part-'+this.newPart);
```